# Best tools for real time audio processing with python

Tags: apache-spark, real-time, audio-processing

I'm currently trying to process .wav files in real time with Apache Spark streaming (pySpark), but I'm facing some problems since I process the audios with pyDub and Librosa, this libraries work with Audisegment objects and numpy arrays, but Apache Spark doesn't work with those types of variables, so I'm currently thinking if there are any other possibilities, such as Apache Flink? or any other tool?

Comment: I know nothing of Spark nor pyDub / Librosa however I do know often times its a one line command to transform or just use as is datastructures especially for audio processing when at first glance the source and target data types appear different ... I would put your shoulder into playing about trying syntax variations ... have fun